# AWS EB CLI - 'eb' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I installed AWS with Python 3.11 in my PC. later I uninstalled Python 3.11 to use Python 3.10 but when I run `aws --version` it still shows Python 3.11.

[image]

When I run other commands like `eb init` it shows and error:

`'eb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

And even if I `pip install awsebcli` it gets installed in Python 3.10. How to fix this?

Comment: Install `awscli` with the new python version and update the windows path

Comment: You did not say what OS you are running the aws-cli tools under, but as @Paolo commented, the cli package or installer, includes an embedded copy of Python with all the libraries it requires, so you won't change anything by upgrading/downgrading the system Python, as that is not used by the cli tools.  The cli tools use whatever version they included.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937100/awscli-python-version-shows-2-7-instead-of-3-6-on-windows-7 The Windows version of the AWS CLI, that is installed via the .msi installer, comes with a bundled version of Python. You don't really need to care about what version the AWS CLI tool is reporting that it is using, as long as it works.

Comment: Also, the `eb` CLI is a completely different tool from the `aws` CLI, and has to be installed separately https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html

Comment: @MarkB it's not just the windows version, as linux packages do the same thing, and I would assume that MacOS does the same.

Comment: @gview it depends on how they are installed, but yes if you don't install them via `pip` then they most likely come with a bundled version of Python.

Comment: @MarkB You also picked up on the OP trying to use the elastic beanstalk cli, which I missed.  So perhaps aws is a complete red herring.  [Instructions for installation and configuration of the eb cli are here](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup).

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the solution is to add the python roaming filepath (besides the local filepath) to the PATH environment variable in Windows 10. See related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729006/unable-to-install-aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-win10-python-3-6-pip-9-0-1
I will add the solution but thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729006/unable-to-install-aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-win10-python-3-6-pip-9-0-1). Basically both `local` and `roaming` filepaths to Python need to be added to the Windows environment variables.

Go to `Start/Edit the system environment variables/Environment Variables...` Once opened, select Path variable and Edit.
Ensure both local and roaming python file paths are added. Eg:

```
C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

Once both are included in the Path variable, run in the command prompt `pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user`. Check it is correctly installed with `eb --version`.